# How to cache index page with pagination?

Tags: ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, activeadmin

Suppose this my one of admin model

```
ActiveAdmin.register Theme do
  menu :if => proc{ current_admin_user.super_admin?}

  after_filter :only => [:create, :update, :destroy] do
    expire_action :action => :show
    expire_action :action => :index
  end

  controller do
    caches_action :index, :show
  end
end
```

with this code caching is done, but on index page with pagination i am facing issue, that is i am not able to visit another page of Theme.

How to implement something like this
https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#creating-friendly-urls-and-caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what fixed the issue:

```
caches_action :index, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }
```

This will generate new cache for specific paginate param's

[Read More](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/3243#issuecomment-47925335)